# Adding Rows to an Index using Multi-level indexing then performing operations on them- Python

Tags: python, pandas

New to Python and Pandas

I'm trying to figure out the best way to take my data frame and do some operations on each row by creating additional rows. This is what I have:

```
         'X     Y'
'Data    50    100'
'Data2   30     70'
```

where my "Data" is indexed. What I'm trying to do is apply operations on each X and Y and run in through a 360 degree sweep so that each "Angle" would sweep so kinda like this:

```
          X    Y   Angle
Data     50   100   0
         55   110   1
         22   40    2

Data 2   30   70    0
         33   15   1
```

Any ideas on how to do this? Basically I will be using the angle and the X and Y values and applying Cosine or Sin Functions to them. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

i suggest add new column (as your Data,Data2) instead of adding new row.
do somethings like that.

```
      X    Y   Angle   Data
     50   100   0       1
     55   110   1       1
     22   40    2       1
     30   70    0       2
     33   15    1       2
```